# Box2d. How to check whether the body to move in the coordinate?

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, collision

Using physical engine **Box2d C++**, how to check the possibility of moving in a straight line a body to coordinate without collision (that is, how to know whether the obstacles to the body to coordinate) ?

**Example:**
We want to move Body A to Body B

Look picture:

[image: Look picture]

Left example - get true, right - false.

Comment: use void b2World::RayCast ( b2RayCastCallback *  callback,
const b2Vec2 &  point1,
const b2Vec2 &  point2 
)   const

Answer (score 0):

I would create a dummy sensor, using the distance between A and B as height and A's width. Place the sensor halfway A and B and rotate it according to the path. Then you can place the sensor in one frame, check for collisions and remove the sensor whenever you want.